DotNet running on macOS does not support TLS1.3
I have tried creating localhost server via python and even dotnet(C#). Also created a client using dotnet(C#), both on macOS(13.6 and 15).
I see the same behaviour that TLS1.3 gets rejected, while others like 1.1, 1.2 works on the same client-server communication.
I used the same code on Windows11, and bang it works.
So, does that mean DotNet doesn't work on macOS?
Any help is highly appreciatedd.

Seems to be an open issue.
